# Font-Awesome 5.9.0 icons not showing up in browsers; but 5.00 versions are

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am working on a site. I have a separate directory for this mini-site inside of the bigger site. In staging (before actual production) all the newer `Font-Awesome` icons showed up, but when I pushed the site so that it was live, any icon after Font Awesome version 5.0.0 no longer showed, giving me a box or blank space instead.

I am hosting it myself, and I have the `all.min.css` pointing to the correct /web fonts folder. Originally, I was getting an error message in the Chrome Console about not being able to find the font, which is why I had to change where it was being pointed to.

I redownloaded the source files from `Font-awesome`, just in case something had happened there, and added them back to the site. Same issue.

The site I am working on, in the "main site" has `Font-Awesome 5.0.0` installed, but the newer version I thought was [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgIuc.png) over-riding the older one. Is it possible that this might not be the case?  Even though the icon is pulling from the `all.min.css` file that is linked directly in the .php file, the page has a template file that includes the older version of Font-Awesome(5.0.0).

Here is what I am referencing as far as the .css file:

```
<link class="rs-file" href="/assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

EDITED: I tried to see if this was just a user-error, but changing the icons and the code still works. I even went in and tried the `pseudo-elements` way, and I got the boxes for these particular icons.

Pseudo-elements code:

```
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #0368b0;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .fa-icon::hover {
    color: #bdd5f6;
  }
  .wallet::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f555";
  }

  .money-check::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f53c";
  }

  .file-invoice-dollar::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f571";
  }
```

[image: Image 2]

Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: refer to this to get more details about the changes: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've gone through that already and unfortunately does nothing to really assist with the issue I'm having.

Comment: share the non working code here, try to create a snippet

Comment: Have you tried the file from their CDN? You posted a link tag that has a relative url (ex /path/to/all.min.css) which means you're pointing to a file on your site. Thatt is useless info we don't have your site address.

Comment: The thing is, @zer00ne, because of the industry I work in, my coworker and I would rather not use CDN and would rather host it ourselves. It's pointing to the correct path/location for sure, since every other icon except the three I have placed in the code snippet work. :(

Comment: Regardless of what you want or required to do in production you need to test with a reliable source. If you get the same results then it's your code. If you get good results then it's the file on your site

Comment: @zer00ne Okay, so Font-Awesome does not have a CDN anymore? I only see kits. Using a kit, the icons show up. So, I am thinking maybe it's the conflict with the two files then?

Comment: @K.Millner FA still runs their CDN or they'll piss off a lot of people. They are up to their shenanigans by omitting info in order to steer users to whatever they're promoting. Here's the latest `<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: @K.Millner BTW your first ruleset has no selector and you should post the relevant HTML that is referenced by said selectors.